# How do I deploy multiple HTML pages on heroku?

Tags: javascript, php, html, heroku

I'm trying to upload a multi-page static website to Heroku. I got it working with one html page, but I'm trying to add reference links to other HTML pages I created for a personal website. Here's the file structure:

[sample file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSquO.png)

In each of the .php files, I have this code:

```
<?php include_once("websiteapp/html/home.html"); ?>
```

where the appropriate html file is referenced for each page I'm trying to render. In the home.html file, I have the code below for the navbar I'm creating:

```
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="websiteapp/html/home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="websiteapp/html/books.html">Library</a></li>
        <li><a href="websiteapp/html/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="websiteapp/html/questions.html">Questions</a></li>
        <li><a href="websiteapp/html/advice.html">Advice</a></li>
        <li><a href="websiteapp/html/health.html">Health</a></li>
        <li><a href="websiteapp/html/deal_memos.html">Deal Memos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

When I launch my Heroku app, it works the first time I click on a link (i.e it takes me to the respective html page). But, when I'm in the second html page, I cannot click the navbar link back to the home page or to any other html page. Does anyone know why? Do I need to modify the php code? The navbar html code above is present in each html file, so the links exist. My composer.json file only contains

```
{}
```

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your `Procfile`?

Comment: Have you checked for any errors on browser console ?

Comment: Procfile is currently empty and there are no errors on build logs on Heroku. Here's what my build log says:

Comment: The error I get when I click a link is "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server."